# Using a repeater without declaring data sources in views

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have the following set up for my aspx page called "Default":

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    IProjectRepository projectRepository = new SPProjectRepository();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel = new HomeViewModel()
        {
            Projects = projectRepository.GetProjects
        };
    }

    public HomeViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

On the aspx page, I have the following which works great:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% foreach( var project in ViewModel.Projects ) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%:project.Title%></td>                    
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*For learning purposes I wanted to know how I would achieve this with a repeater...*

**How do I go about using the repeater much in the same way I have written out direct html code with a foreach loop?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to skip the traditional `DataSource`  approach. But if you are using `ASP.NET 4.5` then you can use the `SelectMethod` (introduced in 4.5 version). Advantage of using this is you can define the `Type` by which your repeater control will bind and in templates you will get intellisense support.

Here is a simple example:-

Suppose you have Customer type:-

```
 public class Customer
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

And if you want a list of customers to Repeater control then you can simply define a method and assign it to repeater control. No extra code like `Datasource`, `DataBind` required.

```
 public IEnumerable rptCustomer_GetData()
 {
     return new List<Customer>
     {
          new Customer { Id =1, Name = "xx" },
          new Customer { Id =2, Name = "yy" }
     };
  }
```

And in repeater just provide that method name:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomer" runat="server" SelectMethod="rptCustomer_GetData" 
                ItemType="Customer">
      <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Id %>'></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Name %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Traditional Data Source Approach:-

In `Page Load` Simply set the Data Source:-

```
rptCustomer.DataSource = projectRepository.GetProjects;
rptCustomer.DataBind();
```

And in mark-up simply use ASP.NET data binding Code nuggets like this:-

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Id %>'>
```

Comment: If the DataSource can be linked to a property on a class, then this is fine, and I would love an example. However, if you are adding direct access to SQL or doing actual SELECT statements in the view, the separation of concerns is non-existant.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - Yup you can. But that is the traditional approach of doing it and you said you didn't wanted to do that :) That is the reason I explained both. :)

Comment: Ah, so it does reference properties, yes, thanks that's even better than above.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**Markup**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ProjectsRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("Title") %></td>                    
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    IProjectRepository projectRepository = new SPProjectRepository();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectsRepeater.DataSource = projectRepository.GetProjects;
        ProjectsRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    public HomeViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

}
```